# How to check if one circle is inside another in corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am making a game where you have to stop a flying circle and if when stopped it is inside another circle (which is non-moving and in the center) you get a point.
How could I check if it's inside the other circle?

[image: First photo]
[image]

Comment: take pen and paper and try to solve it yourself. this is not a thinking service.
at least give us some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
local abs = math.abs
local function distanceBetweenTwoPoints(x1, y1, x2, y2) 
  return (((x2 - x1) ^ 2) + ((y2 - y1) ^ 2)) ^ 0.5 
end 

-- (x1, y1) center and r1 radius of first circle 
-- (x2, y2) center and r2 radius of second circle 
local function circleOverlap(x1, y1, r1, x2, y2, r2)
  return (distanceBetweenTwoPoints(x1, y1, x2, y2) <= r2 + r1)
end

local function oneCircleInsideOther(x1, y1, r1, x2, y2, r2)
  return (distanceBetweenTwoPoints(x1, y1, x2, y2) <= abs(r2 - r1))
end
```

Some tests

```
print(circleOverlap(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2)) -- true
print(circleOverlap(0, 1, 1, 0, 3, 1)) -- false
print(circleOverlap(1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1)) -- false
print(circleOverlap(5, 10, 5, 12, 10, 2)) -- true

print(oneCircleInsideOther(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2)) -- true
print(oneCircleInsideOther(0, 1, 1, 0, 3, 1)) -- false
print(oneCircleInsideOther(1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1)) -- false
print(oneCircleInsideOther(5, 10, 5, 12, 10, 2)) -- false
```

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing from the previous answer:

```
-- (x1, y1) center and r1 radius of first circle 
-- (x2, y2) center and r2 radius of second circle 
-- return true if cirecle 2 is inside circle 1
local function circleInside(x1, y1, r1, x2, y2, r2)
  return (distanceBetweenTwoPoints(x1, y1, x2, y2)+ r2 < r1)
end
```